# Create subset for a list of data frames by name in R

Tags: r, list, filter, subset, lapply

How can I create a subset from a list of data frames by the name of the data frame?

For example,

```
d1<-data.frame(a=rnorm(5), b=c(rep(2006, times=4),NA))
b2<-data.frame(a=1:5, b=c(2007, 2007, NA, NA, 2007))  
my.ls <- list(d1 = d1, b2 = b2)
my.ls
```

Suppose I wanted to select (or filter?) every data frame that contained the letter b in the data frame name, how could I go about this?

I've tried this:

```
flrcp45 <- lapply(my.ls, subset, contains = "b")
```

but it includes everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this (with the inclusion of Laterow's hint):

```
my.ls[grepl("b",names(my.ls))]
$b2
  a    b
1 1 2007
2 2 2007
3 3   NA
4 4   NA
5 5 2007
```

Comment: You don't even need `sapply`: `my.ls[grepl("b",names(my.ls))]`